# IE9 file input is triggering wrong click event

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have some jQuery that allows the user to select all checkboxes by clicking a 'Select all' checkbox.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$('.select-all').on('click', function(){

    // alert($(this).attr('name')); - For debugging

    checkboxes = $(this).closest('.form-item').find('input[type=checkbox]');

    if($(this).attr('checked'))
    {
        $(checkboxes).prop('checked', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $(checkboxes).prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

My 'Select all' checkbox has a class of 'select-all', which when clicked triggers this jQuery code. This all works fine.

Further down the form there is also a file input. Now for some reason in IE9 when the file input field is clicked it's also triggering the code above. The two are not connected in any way.

Here's my file input HTML:

```
<div id="form<?php echo $this->id; ?>_file" class="form-item">

<label for="file" class="mandatory"><span class="invisible">Mandatory field</span> Select file*</label>

    <span class="clearfix"></span>

    <input id="file-input" name="file" type="file" />
    <p class="tl_help tl_tip">Select the file to upload.</p>

</div>
```

Here's the HTML of the checkboxes:

```
<div id="form52_country" class="form-item checkbox-group">
       <label for="country" class="mandatory"><span class="invisible">Mandatory field</span> Country*</label>
       <span class="clearfix"></span>

        <input class="select-all" type="checkbox" name="sa" value="">Select all<br>                      
        <input  type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="al"/>Albania<br>                     
        <input  type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="ar"/>Argentina<br>

        // Rest of checkboxes continue as above
</div>
```

Here's where it gets even stranger. When I uncomment the alert in the jQuery code and try clicking the file input it alerts the name of my 'select all' checkbox button.

Any ideas what is going on here? I can't make any sense of it, it only happens in IE. It seems as if it's treating my file input field as if it were my 'Select all' checkbox field.

Thanks

**Edit - Solved**

Managed to track down the cause of this. I hadn't closed one of my label tags elsewhere in the form, after fixing this the problem stopped.

Comment: Could we maybe see **all** of the relevant HTML? You've mentioned checkboxes, but not shown the HTML for them.

Comment: You're not closing the Select all checkbox tag: `<input class="select-all" type="checkbox" name="sa" value="">`, try changing it to: `<input class="select-all" type="checkbox" name="sa" value=""/>`. It may be treating everything after that as child elements of the checkbox, so the click event bubbles up, though that would be a bit odd.

Comment: Thanks, that was along the right lines. It turned out to be a label tag that wasn't closed. I've closed the input now too just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know its the reason for your conflict.. i've faced the same problem in ie8

```
 <input id="file-input" name="file" type="file" />
```

input to be closed as

```
 <input id="file-input" name="file" type="file" ></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it hasn't resolved it in my case.